# Approximating series with a convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, approximation

I am quite new to the use of little $o$ notation. Suppose that I have a sequence $a_n$ such that $a_n= e^{n(-\alpha+o(1))}$ where $\alpha>0$. It is clear that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n \alpha}$$
converges by a geometric series. What can one say now about
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{n(-\alpha+o(1))}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n\alpha+o(n)}.$$
I thought this may have diverged due to the $o(n)$ in the exponent but I am not too sure how this would work.

Comment: Can you see that $a_n< e^{n(-\alpha/2)}$ for sufficiently large $n$?

Comment: How can $o(1)$ be removed in this inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_n= e^{n(-\alpha+o(1))}$ means that $a_n= e^{n(-\alpha+b_n)}$ with a sequence $(b_n)$ satisfying $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = 0$. It follows that there is an index $N$ such that $b_n < \alpha/2$ for $n \ge N$.

Then $0 < a_n< e^{-n\alpha/2}$  for all $n \ge N$, which implies that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is convergent.

Comment: Due to the ambiguity of $o(1)$ would we have any idea of what $\sum_n a_n$ may converge to?

Comment: @MATHBOI: No, nothing can be said about that. You can modify finitely many elements of a $o(1)$ sequence and it is still $o(1)$. Therefore the value of the series can by anything.